# Backbone.js `el` and `events` not binding properly

Tags: backbone.js

For some reason, while previously working just fine, have `el` and `events` bindings now stopped working properly.

I have had:

```
User.HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#header',
    template: _.template($('#header-template').html()),
    events: {
        "click .login": "login"
    },
    initialize: function(parentView) {
        this.parentView = parentView;
    },
    render: function() {
        this.parentView.render();
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(/* pass model */);
    }
});
```

Previously this worked just fine, but for some reason, `el` no longer correctly binds to `#header` in DOM. Instead, it is instantiated with empty `div`, which can be easily confirmed: if I debug `el` with Firebug (`console.log(this.$el.parent().html()`) I get:

```
null
```

What I'm expecting to get is something like:

```
<div id="header"><ul></ul></div>
```

This is the method I currently use to initialize the views:

```
view.headerView = new HeaderView(parentView);
```

Any ideas how I could fix this or debug further?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/TmBGV/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I clarified the question a bit: I am actually using a parentView, which could be part of the problem.

Comment: `<div id="header"></ul>` is a typo, right?

Comment: Yeah. Should've been `<div id="header"><ul></ul></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialize` expects an object containing the options you wish to pass to your view. Here you pass a view, which is an object and probably has an `el` attribute already set, overwriting the one you declare in `HeaderView`. Try

```
User.HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#header',
    template: _.template($('#header-template').html()),
    events: {
        "click .login": "login"
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.parentView = options.parentView;
    },
    render: function() {
        this.parentView.render();
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(/* pass model */);
    }
});

new HeaderView({parentView:parentView});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works and what's better I now understand how `initialize` should be used!